# Use a Class instance as an property of Another Class

Tags: php, class

I would like to create a class with an instance of another class used as a property.  Something like this:

```
class person
{
    var $name;
    var $address;
}

class business
{
    var $owner = new person();
    var $type;
}
```

This, of course, does not work, and I have tried a few variations.  Everything I have found in Google searches only references nested class definitions (`class a { class b{  } }`).

Is it possible to put a class instance in another class?  If not, is there a reasonable work-around?

Comment: You instantiate your `person` class and set that as the `owner` property value in the `business` class constructor

Comment: But stop using `var` and use proper [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) keywords.... you're not still using PHP4 are you?

Comment: I'm with Mark Baker here, explain why you can't use for instance business::__construct() to set the $owner property? Whether you create that instance of person in the construct or pass it into the constructor as a parameter?

Comment: @qrazi - No particular reason.  I am pretty good at procedural PHP and objective objective C#.  This is my first attempt at objective programming in PHP.  So I am figuring out what my limitations are.  I will probably use a combination of everything mentioned as well as the get_class() function to disallow trying to set the $owner field to the wrong type.

Comment: @Andrew i think you don't need get_class(). If you instantiate in the constructor, you know what class it is. If you take it as a parameter like suchit's answer, it would make sense to type hint that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be try using like this if your intention is to call other class method:

```
class person
{
    public $name;
    public $address;
}

class business {
 public $owner;
    function __construct( $obj ) {
        $this->owner = $obj;
    }

}   
$a = new person();
$b = new business($a);
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer.  I will likely use something similar to this.  My biggest concern was only allowing the person class in attribute $a.  I will probably use the get_class() function to test the validity of the variable passed to the constructor.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew or use type hinting: `function __construct(person $obj)` see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 3):

You can't initialize classes as part of a attribute/property/field declaration.

[From the PHP Property documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [Property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

If you need the new instance to have a property that contains a class instance, you need to assign it in the constructor:

```
class business {
    public $owner;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->owner = new person();
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, be sure to use [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) keywords (`public`, `protected`, `private`) rather than `var`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class person
{
    public $name;
    public $address;
}

class business
{
    public $owner;
    public $type;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->owner = new person();
    }
}
```