# Can instances or objects of any class be treated as attributes in another class?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

While reading Craig Larman's Book (*Applying UML and Patterns;...)* 
I noticed he added instances of Die class as attributes in the DiceGame class.

---

[image: Image of Partial Class Diagram of DiceGame].

---

Is it possible? and there are many related [Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532012/use-a-class-as-an-attribute-of-another-class) where they negate to do so.

Comment: I have no idea why this has been nominated as unclear. The OP obviously had some misunderstanding about instances. But hey, we're here to clarify such kind of issues.

Comment: I thought it was relatively clear as well. I don't have voting rights or I'd help overturn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the question to, "Can *references* to any class be treated as attributes in another class?" The answer is technically "yes", but you shouldn't model it that way in UML. You should model simple values as attributes (inside the class' rectangle), but model non-simple references as associations. Simple values are identified only by their values (e.g., the number 5), whereas non-simple references point to things with identity. In your case, each `Die` should have an identity other than its current face value. Therefore, you should not model attributes of type `Die`, you should model a property at the end of an association.

In the diagram you posted, there are *three* (!!) properties of type `Die`. One is called `die1`, one is called `die2`, and another is unnamed with a multiplicity of `2`. In a programming language, that would give you *four* places to store references to your dice, which is obviously incorrect.

The way I would model it is as follows:

[image]

When you generate code (or transcribe manually), the `dice` property becomes a member variable within `DiceGame`. That member variable is usually typed by a collection in your programming language, but it could also be modeled as an array.  That collection or array allows you to access both of the dice.

Note that the association is unidirectional. That is because there is probably no need for the `Die` to access the `Dice Game`. (However, if you needed each `Die` to be an active object running in its own thread, you may need the association to be bidirectional so each `Die` can send a signal when it's done rolling or something.)

Answer (score 3):

These are not instances of `Die` but simply two properties of type `Die`. The picture is not a very good use of UML (shame on Larman). The association between `DiceGame` and `Die` use a 2 multiplicity. And most likely he means `die1` and `die2` with that. But that would be guessing.  A better notation would be

[image]

with appropriate association-end names.

Comment: That's how I was going to answer, but you beat me to it. I would probably make the associations unidirectional, though, unless a die is asynchronous for some reason and sends signals back to the game.

Comment: @JimL. I should let you a bit more time :-) Honestly I have very much spare time, so I'm on the fast lane. However, your answers are often more thoroughly expressed than mine. Unfortunately they closed this one. It was in no way unclear to me. I'll vote for re-opening so you could answer and I'll take mine back.

Comment: Thanks for the kind thoughts, Thomas! 

Comment: @JimL. So it's open again. Feel free to post your answer :-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian can you recommend another better book for **OOA/D**

Comment: Somebody else just asked and I recommended Doug Rosenberg and ICONIX which helped me some 15 years ago. That was a video tutorial along with a Sparx EA model. No idea whether that's still available.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes... and it happens very often.

In OO there's a neat little trick to figure out if a class should contain a property of some other type of class."Is-A" and "Has-A".

In this case you have a DiceGame class.  You ask yourself, "Is-A" DiceGame a Die, or does DiceGame "Has-A" Die.  If the answer is the former, then you use inheritance, otherwise you have it set as a property(ies) as in the example you posted.

If you had another class called "GamblingRoom", having a DiceGame a property of that "GamblingRoom" class "could" be a viable solution....depending on what you need to do of course.

Here's a better explanation of it in a similar question to what you have.. but probably better explained than what I did here ;)

[HAS-A, IS-A terminology in object oriented language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language)

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question?

Comment: @JimL.  "**How** was it made" is explained well, specially _HAS-A_ and _IS-A_ terminologies helped me.

Comment: @JimL.You asked if this is possible.  I gave you the answer plus a little extra to understand "why" it's that way... and the has-a is-a terminology can help you to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. OOP provides a **container relationship**, which means **has a relation** in which one class can contain instances of another class.

For example, there can be a chair class and a table class and a room class. Now Room can have chairs and tables so room class will have instance of chairs and tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only possible, it's the standard case. In fact, many programming languages make no big difference between classes and elementary data types like `int`.